# I get an error message as follows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java

I get an error message as follows: Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at emp.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:52)
```

Using the following code, how do I alleviate this problem?

```
public class MainClass {
        //main class
public static void main(String[] args){
       // variable

    String input;


    boolean salaryError = true;
    boolean dependentError = true;
    boolean nameError = true;
    boolean charError = true;

    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    displayDivider("EMPLOYEE INFORMATION");


    do{
    input = getInput(" First Name");
    nameError = nameValidate(input);
    if(!nameError){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");
    }
    }while(!nameError);
    emp1.setfirstName(input);
    do{
    input = getInput(" Last Name");
    nameError =nameValidate(input);
    if(!nameError){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");
    }
    }while(!nameError);
    emp1.setlastName(input);
    do{

    input = getInput(" Gender: M or F");

    charError = characterChecker(input.charAt(0));
    if(!charError){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");
    }
    }while(!charError);

    char g = input.charAt(0);
    emp1.setgender(g);// validates use of M or F for gender

    do{
    input = getInput(" number of dependents");
    dependentError = integerChecker(input);
    if(!dependentError){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");
    }
    }while(!dependentError);
    emp1.setdependents(Integer.parseInt(input));

    do{ 
    input = getInput(" annual salary");
    salaryError = doubleChecker(input);
    if(!salaryError){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");
    }
    } while(!salaryError);
    emp1.setannualSalary(Double.parseDouble(input));

    emp1.displayEmployee();//displays data for emp1

    Employee emp2 = new Employee("Speed","Racer",'M',1,500000.00);
    displayDivider("EMPLOYEE INFORMATION");
    emp2.displayEmployee();// displays data for emp2

    terminateApplication(); //terminates application

    System.exit(0);//exits program

}//end of main

    // gets Input information
 public static String getInput(String data)
  {
      String input = "";
      input = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your " + data);
      return input;
  }// end getInput information

    // The display divider between employees
 public static void displayDivider(String outputLab)
  {
      System.out.println("********" + outputLab + "********"); 
}// end display divider

    // Terminates the application
 public static void terminateApplication()
  {   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thanks for the input!"); 

  }// end terminateApplication 
 public static boolean doubleChecker(String inStr){
     boolean outBool = true;
     double tmpDbl = 0.0;
     try{
         tmpDbl = Double.parseDouble(inStr);
         if(tmpDbl <= 0)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }
     catch (Exception e){

         outBool = false;
     }
     return outBool;
 }

 public static boolean integerChecker(String intStr){
     boolean outBool = true;
     int tmpInt = 0;
     try{
         tmpInt = Integer.parseInt(intStr);
         if(tmpInt <= 0)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }
     catch (Exception e){

         outBool = false;
     }
     return outBool;
 }

 public static boolean nameValidate(String str){
        for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
            if(!Character.isDigit(ch)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 public static boolean characterChecker(char gen){
     boolean outBool = true;

     try{

         if(!( gen ==( 'M') || gen ==('F')))
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }
     catch (Exception e){

         outBool = false;
     }
     return outBool;
 }
}//end of Main Class
```

Comment: Check that your string is != null before calling `charAt` on it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Wouldn't that cause a NullPointerException? I was thinking of checking for length > 0, so that there is a character at offset 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It has been resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Your string is length 0.  Make sure `string.length() > 0` before accessing its elements.  The problem is at the line the exception says the problem is on.

Answer (score 0):

Better answer:  are you using an IDE?  If so, observe the line the exception tells you you have an error on.  Set a breakpoint before that line, debug, and note the contents of the object on which the error happened (in this case the string).  Then check the javadoc for the method that threw the exception to see if there is any problem calling that method on that string.

If you are *not* using an IDE, you will either need to use one or find a standalone debugger.  Having a good debugger is a requirement of Java development.

This should save you a lot of SO questions going forward.

Comment: Knowing how to debug is important, but requires neither a debugger nor an IDE, just some way of displaying information at strategically selected points in the code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Can you suggest another way to do this?  Obviously there's print statements but that

Comment: Print statements work. I prefer a good IDE, or debugger, but it is a mistake to get into the mindset of believing that those conveniences are essential for debug. A brain is far more important.

Comment: I did use an IDE. Since its a char, you can't check the length using a string.length. I did get it resolved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[StringIndexOutofBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) means you're try to access the String using an index and the index is either negative or greater than the size of the string.

You're wrong in this part:

```
charError = characterChecker(input.charAt(0));
```

Because you're not check if the input length is 0.

Try to change that line to this:

```
charError = input != null && input.length() > 0 && characterChecker(input.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Thanks! charError = input != null && input.length() > 0 && characterChecker(input.charAt(0)); worked